# connecting the views to the my models in Django

Tags: python, django

I have this data:

```
[
    {
        "x": -1.31242086143345,
        "y": 0.40178573392332,
        "z": -1.02033965707123,
        "ts": 1580485700059,
    }]
```

I posted this data and I received this data with this code in my views:

```
def save_acc(request):
    accelerometer_data = json.loads(request.read())
    return JsonResponse(accelerometer_data,safe=False)
```

I created my model according to each element of the first data:

```
from django.db import models
class accelerometer_data(models.Model):
    x = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10)
    y = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10)
    z = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10)
    ts = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10)
```

So, in mysql database the name of table is accelerometer_data and there are 5 columns:`id, x , y ,z ,ts`
I just need whenever, I post data to my app, I need  directly save data to my database. I think I have to connect my views to my models, for this problem but I do not know how I can do this, thanks for yor help

Answer (score 0):

try this when saving on the db

```
    {
        "x": -1.31242086143345,
        "y": 0.40178573392332,
        "z": -1.02033965707123,
        "ts": 1580485700059,
    }]

accelerometer_data.objects.filter(x=data[0]['x'], y=data[0]['y'],z=data[0]['z'], ts=data[0]['ts']).save()
```

on your views import your model
`from .models import`modelname_here```

Answer (score 0):

After you read the data posted to view create a accelerometer_data object and fill the values then save it.

```
accelerometer_data = request.POST.get("data")
for data in accelerometer_data:
    accelerometer_data.objects.create(x=data['x'], y=data['y'],z=data['z'], ts=data['ts']).save()
```

Something useful: Use CamelCase for model/class names. so AccelerometerData would be the correct name for model.